# Scala Map[String, Int] class cast disaster

Tags: java, scala, avro

Asserting one `Map[String, Int]` to another in a unit test I get:

`Map(bar -> 114, foo -> 5) did not equal Map("foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 114)`

Note the keys are not quoted on the left, but are quoted on the right.

The left has round tripped through Kafka with Avro serialization as part of a GenericRecord.  The right is the test fixture which I constructed like this:

`program_int_args = Map[String, Int]("foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 114)`

Once I get it back from Kafka, I decode the Avro message like this:

```
 val program_int_args_ =
        record.get("program_int_args")
          .asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Integer]]
          .asScala
          .toMap[String, Integer]
          .mapValues(Integer2int(_))
```

Questions:

1. Why the absence of quotes after coming from the GenericRecord?
2. Why the presence of quotes from the constructed map?
3. How can I make these equal?

Per Thomas Klager's comment, I check the classes of the keys, and indeed they are different:

`class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 did not equal class java.lang.String`

So updating the question:

How can the `Utf8` type be a key in a `Map[String, Int]` yet not be equal to the same data as a `String`?

Comment: I suspect that one of the maps (the one returned from avro) doesn't have strings as keys. You could add an assertion to verify or disprove this: `assertEquals(program_int_args.head._1.getClass, program_int_args_.head._1.getClass)`

Comment: _"How can the Utf8 type be a key in a Map[String, Int]"_ Because it probably isn't. Try this: `val aKey = program_int_args_.keySet.head` and then `aKey.split(',')` it should throw an invalid cast exception, and then the culprit would be `.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Integer]]` that is why class cast are unsafe, specially due erasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because of type erasure both conversions

```
.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Integer]]

.toMap[String, Integer]
```

don't really check the type of the keys and values within the map.

You might try

```
val program_int_args_ =
        record.get("program_int_args")
          .asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[Object, Integer]]
          .asScala
          .toMap[Object, Integer]
          .map { case (k, v) => (k.toString, Integer2int(v))}
```

instead, which converts the keys to String.